# Get pointer to memory for which I have the virtual address in a long type value

Tags: python, ctypes, virtual-address-space

I have allocated a memory using a function call, which returned the 64bit Physical Address.
I have mapped that address using a function call, which returned the 64bit Virtual Address.

Now, I need a pointer to access this memory for which I have the virtual address a long type value in Python, I tried using ctypes module pointer() casting but end up in accessing some unbelievable memory

I am accessing like this:

```
VA = Virtual address I got
VA = ctypes.c_uint64(VA)
pVA = pointer(VA)

for i in range(size):
    print pVA[i]
```

Comment: I wish I could get a peek at that *unbelievable* memory! :)

Comment: Could you give a sample of code??

Comment: How are you allocating this memory? Are you saying you want to access it as an array of uint64s?

Answer (score 0):

The code below builds an unsigned 64-bit integer array of *size* elements from a specified address:

```
arr = (ctypes.c_uint64*size).from_address(VA)
for i in arr:
    print i
```

Reference: [from_address](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html?highlight=from_address#ctypes._CData.from_address)